Resize ChartJS chart according to the screen
I'm having trouble creating a responsive application.
function TemperatureChart({keyProp  = '', periodProp  = 'DAILY'} ) {
    const chartRef = useRef(null);
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);
    const [chartDataGradient, setChartDataGradient] = useState({
        datasets: [],
    });

    const [chartHeight, setChartHeight] = useState(200);
    const [chartWidth, setChartWidth] = useState(200);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            const newChartHeight = (window.innerHeight/1080.0) * 600.0;
            const newChartWidth = (window.innerWidth/1920.0) * 1200.0;

            setChartHeight(newChartHeight);
            setChartWidth(newChartWidth);

            console.log("innerWidth: "+window.innerWidth + " / "+ (window.innerWidth/1920.0));
            console.log("chartWidth: "+chartWidth);
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

        handleResize();

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };

    }, [keyProp, periodProp, token]);

    return (
        <div>
            {chartData ? (
                <Chart ref={chartRef} type='line' data={chartData} options={options} width={chartWidth} height={chartHeight}/>
            ) : (
                <Grid container spacing={16} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" style={{}}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                            <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <CircularProgress/>
                                <p style={{marginTop: '80px',marginLeft: '10px'}}>Carregando informações...</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default TemperatureChart;

I need the above component to resize itself according to screen resolution changes.
This component is the child object of another component called CustomCard, which resizes normally.
                <CustomCard index={9} xs={12} height={650}
                            title={
                                <div>
                                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                        <Grid item xs={9}>
                                            Horimetro
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                                            <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ height:5 }}>
                                                <InputLabel id="hourmeter-select-label">Periodo</InputLabel>
                                                <Select
                                                    labelId="hourmeter-select-label"
                                                    id="hourmeter-select"
                                                    label="Periodo"
                                                    value={hourmeterPeriodState}
                                                    onChange={handleHourmeterPeriodChange}
                                                >
                                                    <MenuItem value="DAILY">Diario</MenuItem>
                                                    <MenuItem value="WEEKLY">Semanal</MenuItem>
                                                    <MenuItem value="MONTHLY">Mensal</MenuItem>
                                                </Select>
                                            </FormControl>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </div>
                            }
                            content={<HourmeterChart nameProp = {nameFormmated} periodProp = {hourmeterPeriodState} />} />

CustomCard (content receives TemperatureChart):
function CustomCard ({ index, xs, height, content, title }) {
    return (
        <Grid key={index} item xs={xs}>
            <Card sx={{ height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <CardContent style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '100%' }}>
                    {title}
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        {content}
                    </Box>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default CustomCard;

I made some functions to handle the resizing, I called them handleResize (in TemperatureChart's useEffect):
However, after the screen changes its size, chartWidth and chartHeight remain with the values set at the beginning of the application, when hadleResize is run the first time, and not the value changed in setChartHeight(newChartHeight); and setChartWidth(newChartWidth);.
Console log with the innerWidth and chartWidth information
I also tried a way of using only style in the chart div:
 <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
            {chartData ? (
                <Bar options={options} data={chartData} height={(200)}/>
            ) : (
                <Grid container spacing={3} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" style={{}}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                            <div style={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <CircularProgress/>
                                <p style={{marginLeft: '10px'}}>Carregando informações...</p>
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            )}
        </div>

It worked well for when I shrink the screen, the charts shrink together, but when I enlarge, the charts remain small. As in the image:
Screenshot after enlarging, but charts remain small
